# SQL Server 2008: What are the English Word Breakers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm trying to replicate what SQL Server 2008 is doing when generating full-text indexes, but I'm having a hard time finding a list of which characters SQL Server 2008 considers to be word breakers.

Is there a list out there specifying which characters SQL Server 2008 will break words on for full-text indexes for English?

Answer (score 7):

The per language noise list (also referred to as stop list) and thesaurus files are in the MSSQL/FTData/ folder. The noise files are plain text, the thesaurus XML, so both can be inspected or changed easily.

[Configuring Full-Text Linguistic Components](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142581.aspx) in BOL has the details.

Comment: I'm looking for the criteria where SQL server breaks up the words.. i.e. "Hello World" gets broken into two due to the space

Comment: @John - its in the link he posted....maybe read it first.

Comment: @JNK: where does it list out the word breakers?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187985.aspx

Comment: took me 2 clicks to get there from his link

Comment: someone woke up on the wrong side of the bed... the query "sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'wordbreaker'" does not return the list; just the registered libraries